# Adding design-time support for a nested container in a custom/usercontrol (Winforms)

Tags: .net, winforms, design-time

I have something similar to a wizard control, in the middle is a Panel I would like to use to place any child controls.

I have found using the ScrollableControlDesigner will allow dropped controls to be added to the custom/usercontrol, but this is not what I require. It needs to be added to the container, so layout can be applied without affecting the 'outer' controls (heading, navigation buttons).

I have tried various ways, that did not work, and looked hacky.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.windowsforms.designtime/2005-11/msg00060.html)!

The key is `ControlDesigner.EnableDesignMode()`.